# INSERT statement that does not fire an INSERT trigger

Tags: postgresql, insert, postgresql-9.2

I am using PostgreSQL 9.2 and I need to write an INSERT statement which copies data from table A to table B without firing the INSERT trigger defined on table B (maybe some sort of bulk insertion operation??).

On this specific table (table B) many INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE operations are executed. During each and every one of this executions, a trigger must fire.

I cannot temporary disable the triggers because of standard, day-to-day DML operations.

Can anyone help me with the syntax for this non-trigger-firing INSERT statement?

Answer (score 1):

Run your "privileged" inserts as a different user. That way your trigger can check the current user and exit if it shouldn't do anything.

Comment: Then you'll need to give us a hint as to what is different between a "normal" insert and a "special" one.

Comment: Standard inserts must fire trigger since from trigger other inserts occurs. This 'special insert' is meant for table only. 
Problem is that same user (from the same application) must execute 'standard' and 'special' insert. 

I was wondering is there any way for the same user to execute insert, but some are 'normal'(trigger will fire) and some are not(trigger will not fire).

Comment: I'll try again. WHAT IS DIFFERENT ABOUT THE TWO TYPES OF INSERT? If you printed both queries and showed them to me, how would I tell which was which?

Comment: There is no difference between inserts. Both are classic inserts. BUT, I want for one not to fire trigger. I called it 'special' because this inserts purpose is to populate just this one table, and trigger must not fire so the other tables would not get populated. Both inserts are called from same application so the same user calls both inserts. My question is: is there a kind of insert statement that will not fire trigger on purpose. Answer NO is acceptable. I just wanted to know. If there is no such insert statement, I will find other way. I just thought this will be more simple way.

Comment: No, there's no "INSERT-WITHOUT-TRIGGERS" command. I'm not sure it would make sense to have one. After all, it's only the one trigger you want to disable. Like I said, consider using a different DB user - maybe wrap the insert in a "security=definer" function if your app can't support multiple DB users.